Convert Python networkx graph to RDF format
I want to load a graph in python, use a list of nodes of interest, and select all the predecessors nodes to create a subgraph that keep only the nodes that lead to the nodes in the previously mentionned list. I would like to be able to load the resulting graph in the Protégé software so I need to convert it back to RDF format.
I load the ontology database with this code:
url = "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/hp.obo"
graph = obonet.read_obo(url)

I then create my subgraph easily, but I can't find a way to save it in RDF format (.obo or .owl). Is it possible to do so? If not is it possible to do the manipulations mentionned above without changing the format of the file in the first place?
Here is the code that I use to create the subgraph:
df_nodes = pd.read_csv('./code_test.csv', header = None)
nodes = list(df_nodes[0])

def predecessor_nodes(node):
    node_list.append(node)
    pred = graph.predecessors(node)
    for node2 in pred:
        return predecessor_nodes(node2)

node_list = []
for node in nodes:
    predecessor_nodes(node)
node_set = set(node_list)
node_list = list(node_set)

result = graph.subgraph(node_list)

!

there is no built-in function to convert the NetworkXX graph back to OBO format. Note, your file is not RDF but OBO format. What you indeed could do is to extract the subgraph by traversing the OBO structure, I mean according to NetworkXX docs it's just "The induced subgraph of the graph contains the nodes in nodes and the edges between those nodes." - that sounds trivial, most of the OBO stuff are attributes, so you only have to check for the xref and is_a I guess.

For RDF graphs it's also possible to get the induced subgraph similar to the NetworkXX implementation, especially it's just edges between the given nodes, not paths according to their docs. So you could use rdflib or even SPARQL to get the subgraph
